# me dice null al guardar los datos en php

Tags: php, mysql

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un insert pero me aparece
Error Null
no me esta tomando la informacion mi POST y nose que sea ya revise la conexion y esta bien a continuacion dejo el formulario

```
<form action="create.php">
<input type="text"  name="nombre_cliente"  id="nombre_cliente" placeholder="Nombre de Cliente" required>
<input type="text"  name="Numero_ticket"  id="Numero_ticket" placeholder="Número de ticket" required>
<input type="text"  name="Correo"  id="Correo" placeholder="Correo Electronico" required>

<input class="btn-primary" type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar" />
</div>
</form>
```

y aqui dejo lo de la pagina create.php
el cual me inserta los datos en la tabla almacenada pero dichos datos me dice null

```
<?php
//establezco la zona horaria por defecto
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_city');



//si el formulario ha sido enviado procedo a ingresar contenido en la bbdd



include("configuracion.php");


$nombre_cliente=!empty($_POST['nombre_cliente']) ? $_POST['nombre_cliente'] : NULL;
$Numero_ticket=!empty($_POST['Numero_ticket']) ? $_POST['Numero_ticket'] : NULL;
$Correo=!empty($_POST['Correo']) ? $_POST['Correo'] : NULL;



$sql = "INSERT INTO clientesdel (nombre_cliente,Numero_ticket,fecha_creada,Correo) VALUES ($nombre_cliente,$Numero_ticket, NOW(),$Correo )";

$data = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
var_dump($Numero_ticket);

if($data)

{
 /* echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Guardado Exitosamente!");
    window.location.href="supervisor.php";
  </script>';*/
}else{
  echo 'error';
 // var_dump($sql);
}






?>
```

Answer (score 1):

YA ENCONTRE MI ERROR
solo tenia que agregar los comillas en el insert ''

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clientesdel (nombre_cliente,Numero_ticket,fecha_creada,Correo) VALUES ('$nombre_cliente','$Numero_ticket', NOW(),'$Correo' )";
```